# parameterize a half disk of radius 2

Tags: vector-analysis

Is it possible to parameterize the equation $x^2 + y^2 < 4$ with $x = 2 \cos(\theta)$ and $y = 2 \sin( \theta)$?

I can't see how not to include the full half disk without including the boundaries.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. The equation $x^2+y^2<4$ describes the (open) disk or radius 2 around the origin. The parameterization you gave trace out (the entire) boundary of said region.

Comment: Does the parameterization satisfy the equation? I'm confused because the parameterization I gave traces out the entire boundary of the region, but the equation is strictly less than 4, not x^2 + y^2 = 4

Comment: Your equation satisfies the equation $x^2+y^2=4$. If you only want to capture the interior, consider the parameterization $x(r,\theta)=r\cos(\theta), y(r,\theta)=r\sin(\theta)$, where $r\in[0,2)$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$.